# Cypress get global variable from window

Tags: javascript, user-interface, testing, global, cypress

Why can't I get the content of a global variable (attached to the `window` object?) with [Cypress](https://cypress.io)?
I've tried many different things and ended up with this, which still doesn't work:

```
it('blabla', () => {...
var arr = [];
cy.window()
        .then((win) => {
            cy.log(win);
            arr = win.teasers;
        })
        .then(() => {
            arr.forEach(function (el, i) {
                cy.get('h1').should('be.visible');
                cy.get('h1').should('have.text', win.teasers[i]);
                cy.tick(11800);
            });
        });
...});
```

It errors with `ReferenceError: win is not defined`, even though it logs `window` above just fine, and that logged object also contains the `teasers` array as a property. Why won't it work with the second line in the first `.then()` when it does log it in the first?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:** Commenting out the above snippet and executing the following assertion instead:

```
cy.window().should('have.property', 'teasers');
```

Works just fine. This means that the property MUST exist, and leaves the question why I can't iterate over that array then?

Comment: I'm curious if just `cy.window().should('have.property', 'abc', true);` passes, inside the `it` block, with no other assertions or usages of `cy.window().`

Comment: @JakeWorth I've logged the cy.window() object and it seems to contain the 'abc' variable as a property, as expected. The should() assertion is working fine, too :/

Comment: @JakeWorth Oh, after commenting the snippet in my question out and just laving the should() assertion, it complains about the property being an `[ Array(10) ]`, not of type `true` as asserted. While this renders the assertion bad, this means that the property DOES exist. Why can't I iterate over that array, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`win` is not in scope in the second `then()`, hence the error `ReferenceError: win is not defined`. It's only available once, in the first `then()`.

Since the value of `arr` has already been set to `win.teasers` by the time the second `then()` executes, change this:

```
cy.get('h1').should('have.text', win.teasers[i]);
```

To this:

```
cy.get('h1').should('have.text', arr[i]);
```